Pip install freeze inside python Docker image
Pip install freeze inside python Docker image. However on other Linux machine it launches right away.
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                                                                                   0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 390B                                                                                                                                                                                                   0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/python:3.11                                                                                                                                                                         1.1s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                                                                                      0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                                                                                                        0.0s
 => [1/7] FROM docker.io/library/python:3.11@sha256:58ef3c375e20ca749f5bf4d1a62186a01e9d1d5756671037e391c832a5062d1e                                                                                                                   0.0s
 => [internal] load build context                                                                                                                                                                                                      0.0s
 => => transferring context: 255.02kB                                                                                                                                                                                                  0.0s
 => CACHED [2/7] WORKDIR /code/src                                                                                                                                                                                                     0.0s
 => CACHED [3/7] COPY ./requirements.txt /code/requirements.txt                                                                                                                                                                        0.0s
 => CACHED [4/7] RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -U pip                                                                                                                                                                                 0.0s
 => [5/7] RUN pip install --no-cache-dir --upgrade --default-timeout=5000 -r  /code/requirements.txt                                                                                                                                8377.6s
 => => # WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ReadTimeoutError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=5000.0)")': /s
 => => # imple/pydantic/
client_loop: send disconnect: Connection reset

Sometimes it fails on step 4 with same warning.
Docker file:
FROM python:3.11

ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

WORKDIR /code/src

COPY ./requirements.txt /code/requirements.txt

RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -U pip
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir --upgrade --default-timeout=5000 -r  /code/requirements.txt

COPY ./ /code/src
ENV PYTHONPATH /code/src

RUN chmod a+x run.sh
CMD ["./run.sh"]

Any package installation causes freeze. Python docker image without pip upgrade and pip install works fine.
I would really appreciate any advice at all.

The warning says that pip cannot connect to the pypi server from which pip tries to pull the Python modules. I'm not really familiar with Docker, but I guess you need to provide some additional parameters to pip or configure networking in the container differently, as pip seems not to have direct access to the internet.
